# TypeScript: What is the difference between declaring variables inside the constructor and outside of it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

let's assume that I have a class written in TypeScript like this:

```
class Messenger { 
    x = 10;
    constructor(){
      this.y = 20;
    }
};
```

the JavaScript version of this will look like:

```
var Messenger = (function () {
    function Messenger() {
        this.x = 10;
        this.y = 20;
    }
    return Messenger;
}());
;
```

The x and y variables are compiled to the same thing in JavaScript so what is the difference here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually correct TypeScript:

```
class Messenger { 
    x = 10;
    y: number;

    constructor() {
        this.y = 20;
    }
}
```

You must declare properties of the class (not needed in JavaScript).
As it compiles to the same think in JavaScript there is no difference in runtime. But is some cases it easier to write just `x = 10` (property is correctly typed as number) than `y: number` + `this.y = 20` - so if you have default value for properties that are not coming from parameters then you can write it in less characters.

Answer (score 0):

It does compile, however the compiler should give you an error message, that y is not part of class Messenger right here:

```
constructor(){
  this.y = 20;
}
```

However the compiler will often compile regardless of errors, unless you turn it off in your `tsconfig.json`. However there is a way to declare a variable inside the constructor, but it's not in the body but in the parameter list. Like this:

```
 constructor(public y: number){}
```

Either put `private` or `public` in front of them. This way the variable is automatically set to whatever you insert into the constructor without having to do `this.y = y;`. It's a very easy way of creating variables that you will always insert into the constructor.

You can even give a default parameter, that will work if you don't insert any arguments into the constructor:

```
 constructor(public y = 20){}
```

Check out [this article](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way, your code:

```
class Messenger { 
    x = 10;
    constructor(){
      this.y = 20;
    }
};
```

Is exactly the same like this:

```
class Messenger {
   x = 10;
   y = 20;
   constructor() { }
}
```

Because is the same to have this:

```
class Greeter {
   greeting: string;
   constructor(message: string) {
      this.greeting: string;
   }
}
```

that to have:

```
class Greeter { constructor(greeting: string) }
```

Actually you are doing the same, you are declaring a class property and if it is passed in the construction it will be assined, in other case it will be `undefined`.
Is only a proper way to avoid innecesary code in TypeScript.